# How do I get the Kindle Fire Browser to display a JSON response in place?

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, kindle-fire

I have a ASP.NET Web API endpoint. When testing the endpoint in the browser on my Kindle Fire,  the JSON response does not display in the browser. Instead, a .bin file is downloaded. How do I get the browser to display the JSON ?

I have full control over the web API (designed, wrote, deployed, own the server, etc. etc.) so I , hopefully, can make this work.

Comment: What are the `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition` headers that you're sending? Have you tried `Content-Type: text/plain` and `Content-Disposition: inline`?

Comment: Content-Type is application/json. I have not tried content disposition but I will. Thanks!